Azure DevOps pipeline notification to teams direct message
I am working on pipeline that takes care of pull requests. Everything about it works fine, howerver I would like to notify the developer for which the pull request pipeline is running if the pipeline stops (fail or success). Is it possible to send them a notification through direct message. I dont want to have a teams chat full of these types of notifications, that seems unorganized.
I am expecting a notification in developers dms.
Correction to the question: We are using Teams. I want to send a Teams dm to the author of the pull request when pipeline that was running for given pull request fails or succeeds.


Is it possible to send them a notification through direct message.

Option1: Using custom notifications in Azure DevOps
It's suggested to create custom notifications. Go to Project Settings -> Notifications -> New Subscription -> Build -> A build completes -> Customize notification according to your needs.


Description: The description of your notification
Deliver to: You can deliver to Custom email address, Members of ** Team by role, Team preference, Members of ** Team and SOAP.
Filter criteria: Use filters to send notification for specific builds. In your case, you can set "Build reason = Pull request or shelveset validation" and "Definition name = your PR build".

Result: The user will receive notifications in the email like:

See the details from Manage notifications for a team, project, or organization.
Option2: Using pipelines subscriptions in Teams
If you want your team to receive notifications in Teams channel, you can set up the Azure Pipelines app in Teams and create pipelines subscriptions. Using this method, all users in the channel can see the notification.
See the details from Integrate Azure Pipelines with Microsoft Teams.

Update:
To send notifications to the creator of the source branch of the PR, you can change the notification as mentioned below.

Change Deliver to to Members of ** Team by role. You need to add the branch creator to the target team.
Set Roles to Requested for.



my apologies for inaccurately expressed question. I would like to single out the developer that is author of the branch that is being tested and send him a notification about the status of the tests. Success or Fail based on pipeline status. Is there a way to achieve this? Right now I am looking for solution in Microsoft Power Automate, or incoming webhooks (they seem to not work at all)

"single out the developer that is author of the branch that is being tested" - Are you talking about the creator of the source branch of the PR or the creator of the source branch of the validation pipeline?

Creator of the source branch for the PR

Hi @Kopolomo03, you can do it by changing the notification settings. See my update for details.
